# Audio was out of sync whenever I didn't play it from the start

Tags: animation, audio

Whenever I don't play the animation from the start, the audio would be out of sync (I'm animating a part of a music video), and when its out of sync it'll probably be hell to try to do lip-syncing. I've tried stuff like making the audios length the same of the actual project (which didn't work).

Comment: It's hard to guess what the cause may be in your particular case, so preparing some example .blend file reproducing your problem could help others to figure out what's going on. I only ever got a desync when my scene was lagging, indicated by red FPS number during playback, but it could as well be a codec problem.

Comment: First make sure that the audio is in WAV format, not in mp3. Then, in the timeline Playback options set the Audio Sync either to frame dropping or AV-sync.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209987/2-audio-was-out-of-sync-whenever-i-didnt-play-it-from-the-start